# Migrating to web application with AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ajaxcontroltoolkit, web-config

We are currently migrating our ASP.NET website to a web application in Visual Studio 2008. Most of the process has been fairly straight forward, but I have hit one block that is driving me a bit nuts.

We are using the AjaxControlToolkit for some functionality, specifically an AutoControlExtender. When this is run locally through VS's development server the extender (dropdown) does not render after the service returns the resultset. However if I deploy the migrated solution to our UAT server the extender functions correctly.

I have ensured the Ajax Control Toolkit is properly installed locally on my dev machine (and the dll available in the bin directory), and using debugging have ensured the service is called correctly and runs through without error (which it does). The web application was taken from a server running IIS7.

Can anyone confirm if Visual Studio 2008 development server requires a different configuration to IIS 7 (as I believe IIS 6 requires a different configuration to IIS 7), and if there is a resource that provides more info? My own searches have turned up very little in this area.

On the other hand, if I am looking in the wrong area any other tips would be appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally found the problem, and commenting if anyone gets this in the future.

In our solution the specific folder the page was in had a secondary web.config file. There was not much in there, it seemed to exist for historical reasons.

Removing the secondary file seemed to allow VS's web server to load the correct configuration from the root web.config, and the drop down worked.